# fast way to check a number is in a range of a group of numbers

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I just encounter a scenario like the following. It sounds a little bit like a leetcode question.

Support I can get a list of number in a pattern, to simplify my questions.

For example, `[0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25]` or `[0,7,14,21]`, it's already sorted.

then given a `range` (I can guarantee range will never overlap between two consecutive numbers)

for example, `range=2`;

If `num=11`, then I supports to get `index of 10` because `11` is in a range of `10-2` to `10+2`.

If `num=12.5`, then I will just return `-1` or anything else to indicate we does not find.

I can simply go through the list and check if the number is in the range of each number but I feel like there is a O(1) solution since the list itself has some pattern exist. any help is greatly appreciated.

`Diff` is also provided, the above example `diff=5`.

I does not encounter any performance issue now with O(N) list checking, just want to make thing better.

Comment: Not clear enough...
Why 13 not good?  it's 2 away from 15, so index of 15?

Comment: do you have some more examples and your try?

Comment: @iAmOren, sorry for misleading,  I should  say 12.5. It doesn't need to be integer,  I will correct it now

Comment: Whilst the lists do have patterns, the only way to determine that pattern is to look at all the values in the list. Or do you know that the list starts at 0 with increments of 5? In which case there is a O(1) solution.

Comment: @fubar yes, I can make it start 0 with same increments/diff

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my shot at an O(1) solution.

```js
const list = [0, 7, 14, 21, 28];
const interval = list[1];
const range = 2;

function getIndex(num, range) {
  const halfItvl = interval / 2;
  const inRange = Math.abs((num % interval) - halfItvl) >= halfItvl - range;

  return inRange ? Math.trunc((num + halfItvl) / interval) : -1;
}


// Test for all numbers within the list
for (var i = 0; i < list[list.length - 1]; i++) {
  const res = getIndex(i, range);

  if (res === -1) {
    console.log(`${i} is out of range ${range}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${i} is within range ${range} of index ${res}`);
  }

  if (i % interval === interval - 1) {
    console.log("---------------------");
  }
}
```

---

Actually, it seems a good bit simpler if I establish the index first. Then all we need to do is subtract the current number from the value at the found index, take its *absolute* value, and see if it's less than or equal to the given range number.

```js
const list = [0, 7, 14, 21, 28];
const interval = list[1];
const range = 2;

function getIndex(num, range) {
  const idx = Math.trunc((num + (interval / 2)) / interval);
  
  return Math.abs(list[idx] - num) <= range ? idx : -1;
}


// Test for all numbers within the list
for (var i = 0; i < list[list.length - 1]; i++) {
  const res = getIndex(i, range);

  if (res === -1) {
    console.log(`${i} is out of range ${range}`);
  } else {
    console.log(`${i} is within range ${range} of index ${res}`);
  }

  if (i % interval === interval - 1) {
    console.log("---------------------");
  }
}
```

Comment: I eventually come out a idea, it's pretty close to yours. `remainder = num % interval ` then check `remainder <= 2 ` and `remainder + 2 >= interval` to determine if it falls into catergory.

Comment: @Yunhai: Nice, so then do you use those comparisons to determine if you should return the lower index vs the higher one?

Comment: exactly,  `Math.floor( num / interval )` to get `quotient / lower index` , then the result will either be `quotient `, `quotient + 1 (higher index)` or `-1 (outofrange)`

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Array.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if the number (and range) overlaps with your list, for example:

This will be O(n), and I suspect you will need a very large list indeed to justify creating an O(1) type solution.

We can go the other way, creating an array of candidate numbers (numbers within the range, e.g. for 10 +- 2 this would be [8,9,10,11,12]. NB: This approach will not work for floating point values.

We check each number for membership of a set created from the list. This will still technically be O(n), but N will most likely be small (e.g. 5).

```js
let list = [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25];

// This solution will need at most N iterations, where N is the length of list
function checkInRange(value, range, list) {
    return list.some((el) => {
        return (el >= (value - range)) && (el <= (value + range));
    })
}

// This solution will need at most N iterations, where N is the length of a, e.g. 2 * range + 1
function checkInRangeSet(value, range, list) {
    // Create an array of matching numbers, e.g. 8,9,10,11,12
    let a = Array.from({ length: 2*range + 1 }, (v,k) => value - range + k);
    let set = new Set(list);
    return a.some((el) => {
        return set.has(el);
    })
}

console.log("Solution with simple loop");
console.log(checkInRange(11, 1, list));
console.log(checkInRange(10, 0, list));
console.log(checkInRange(30, 5, list));

console.log(checkInRange(9, 0, list));
console.log(checkInRange(100, 20, list));


console.log("Solution with Set");
console.log(checkInRangeSet(11, 1, list));
console.log(checkInRangeSet(10, 0, list));
console.log(checkInRangeSet(30, 5, list));

console.log(checkInRangeSet(9, 0, list));
console.log(checkInRangeSet(100, 20, list));
```